# why does setHours function change date also in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
    const day  = new Date(1578558324000)
    const nextDay = new Date(day)
    nextDay.setDate(nextDay.getDate() + 1)
    console.log(day)
    console.log(nextDay)
```

From the  timestamp I want to add + 1 day with dafault time 00:00:00.If I  set this nextDay.setHours(0,0,0,0) ,it also changes the date.

Comment: I suppose it's your [timezone](https://medium.com/@toastui/handling-time-zone-in-javascript-547e67aa842d)

Comment: Your code isn't using `setHours()`.

Comment: Can you explain what is the expected output vs the output that you are getting?

Comment: please note that console.log a Date object outputs the date at UTC - if you `console.log(date.toLocaleString())` you'll see your local time instead

Comment: @Ahmad From the timestamp I want to add + 1 day with dafault time 00:00:00.If I set this nextDay.setHours(0,0,0,0) ,it also changes the date.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, using setUTCHours:

```js
const day = new Date(1578558324000);
const nextDay = new Date(day);
nextDay.setDate(nextDay.getDate() + 1);
console.log(day);

nextDay.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

console.log(nextDay);
```

Take into account the `setHours` function depends on local time: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours

Comment: can I compare new Date() with the nextDay in my production ?like new Date() > nextDay ?

Comment: Timezone for `nextDay` won't be changed after this, so as long as it represents the 00:00 hours in the timezone you expect, that should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The `Date`-functions are using local time. So it may be your [timezone](https://medium.com/@toastui/handling-time-zone-in-javascript-547e67aa842d). Setting UTC-values may circumvent the problem.

```js
const day  = new Date(1578558324000)
const nextDay = new Date(day);
nextDay.setUTCDate(nextDay.getDate() + 1);
nextDay.setUTCHours(0);
nextDay.setUTCMinutes(0);
nextDay.setUTCSeconds(0);
nextDay.setUTCMilliseconds(0);
console.log(`initial`, day);
console.log(`next`, nextDay);
```

Comment: can I compare new Date() with the nextDay in my production ?like new Date() > nextDay ?